# SequelizeUniqueConstraintError create method add only one row

Tags: node.js, csv, sequelize.js, fast-csv

I am trying to parse a csv file with fast-csv and at the end store all the lines in a database with sequelize

Here is my script to parse the data:

```
module.exports = async () => {
  try {
let csvData = [];

    csv
      .parseFile(__basedir + "/test.csv", { headers: true })
      .on('data', (data) => {
        csvData.push(data);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
          Card_Report.bulkCreate(csvData)
      });
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Something went wrong', e)
  }
}
```

Here is my table model:

```
  const Test= sequelize.define(
      'test',
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          primaryKey: true,
          defaultValue: uuidv4(),
          allowNull: false
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        age: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }
        }, {
            createdAt: false,
            updatedAt: false,        
            tableName: 'test'
         }
    )
    return Test
  }
```

and here is my csv file :

```
name, age  
nina, 24
sarah, 23
```

when I run the script I get this error :

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
```

But when there is only one row in my csv file it adds the row to the table correctly

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like an issue with a primary key, since Sequelize says about `UniqueConstraint`. Please check if your PK in the database is not `null` for both parsed persons. Also, do you have `uuid` package installed, because you call its `uuidv4` function?

Comment: As a side note, instead of try/catch I'd listen to 'error' event during the stream

Comment: @Ilya Kushlianski it returns the same primary key like this :
INSERT INTO `card_report` (`id`,`name`,,`age`) VALUES ('2ab2c36b-8907-4c15-9b0d-966d04c82a67','nina','24'),('2ab2c36b-8907-4c15-9b0d-966d04c82a67','sarah', '23');
what can cause this as I have set a default value in the model           defaultValue: uuidv4(),

Comment: @Ilya Kushlianski  yes for the uuid I declared it this way 
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are getting the same id, because all models in Sequelize are "prepared" once, and your function `uuidv4()` runs only once. Thus for every row you insert into the DB it will have the same uuid. You could try mitigating it like this:

```
id: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, <- try something like this
  primaryKey: true,
},
```

Thus you are shifting responsibility for generating a unique UUID for each row on the database

P.S.: You might need a uuid extension for your DB, something like this:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```